# How to set a custom 410 page on liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, http-status-code-410

I want to set a custom 410 page on liferay. I have already configured that for a 404 page via the file portal-ext.properties

```
layout.friendly.url.page.not.found=/html/portal/404.html
```

But I don’t know how to do it for a 410 page.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such configuration option. If you look at the code of `PortalImpl.sendError` you will see, that there is a special test for `NoSuchLayoutException`. All other errors are just redirected to the *status* page.

You could either create an *EXT plugin* and overwrite `PortalImpl.sendError` to do whatever you want. Or you create a *hook* and overwrite `/html/portal/status.jsp`.

Comment: To add on to Tobias's answer,currently the given list(403,404,400,500) is being handled in PortalImpl.java.It is more advisable to go for overrding status.jsp using hook,to have a cleaner solution.